# Cant compare coordinate to a number

Tags: julia

I want a function that receives a `coordinate(xyz(…,…,…))` and tells me in which quadrant it is.

For example:
`point.x >> 0 && point.y >>0`

But it gives me the error “`no method matching ››(: : Float64, :: Int64)`”
How do i make this work?

Comment: You probably wanted `point.x > 0 && point.y > 0`, where the only doubled sign is the ampersand (`&&` is logical and, a single `&` is bitwise and).

Answer (score 1):

The error message comes from the fact that `>>` is a bitshift operator. You wanted `>` which is greater than.